# How can I wire switch to convert a regular outlet to half switch?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I have a junction box with 2 switches:
- Right switch controls the ceiling fan.
- Left switch does nothing, but the black(hot) wire is labeled "Fan". The white neutral wire is not attached.[image] 
[image: switch view 1]![enter image description here]

I'm trying to wire one of the outlets to be a half-switch controlled by the extra switch.
- all the outlets have 2 black wires attached to them and 2 white wires.

[image: outlet view]

Is this possible without running additional wiring?

I had the house fully renovated last year but the GC did not ask me how I wanted to rooms wired despite me clearly stating this was to be the case.

Answer (score 1):

No. Definitely NO way to make that receptacle switched in any way without running new wire.

Sorry.

Looks like those two switches were intended to control a fan and light separately. Notice how the black and red are in the same cable? That cable goes up to the fan/light.